# How to layout PyTest Fixtures and multi-line strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm looking for a way to layout pytest fixtures in a more elegant way.

Right now my test directory looks like this:

```
.
└── test
    └── cli
        ├── test_compile.py
        └── testdata
            └── ...
```

In test_compile, I have a series of tests, each of which uses a fixture as input (a string). Right now, I lay out all the multi-line strings at the bottom of the file. So it looks like this:

```
def test_parse_zero_steps():
    _testStep(1, 1, py_zero_steps, "ZERO_STEPS")


py_zero_steps = """
# ---

foo = "bar"

# +
import tensorflow
"""
```

`_testStep` is an internal function that I pass a series of parameters to to assert if I parsed the blob correctly.

This is already pretty unwieldy, and I have 20+ strings I need to use here to test edge cases. Is there an elegant/more-pythonic way to do this? I looked at parameterization (https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html) which looks much nicer, but it still isn't clear what I'm supposed to do with these large/annoying strings. Put them all in their own separate files?

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't be able to put the multi-line string in the test case itself? e.g. like

```python
def test_input_1(input):

    expected = '''
    # ---

    foo = "bar"

    # +
    import tensorflow
    '''

    actual = some_py_call(input)

    assert actual == expected
```

Comment: oh for sure, but it makes it hard to edit (if necessary - unlikely, but possible), and makes the series of tests super noisy to look through. Some of the multiline strings are real world strings, and can be quite large (~2000 characters or more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all your tests will just call `_testSteps`, the best way to do this is probably using `parametrize`, as already mentioned in the question. The test data could be in a separate file, either as a Python variable or function, or as a json file (or some other format) that can be read by `parametrize`.

Here is a simple example using a Python function:

```py
def params():
    return [
        (
            1, 1, """
# ---

foo = "bar"

# +
import tensorflow
""",
            "ZERO_STEPS"
        ),
        (
            1, 2, """
# something sensible
""",
            "ONE_STEP"
        ),
...
    ]
```

This can than be used in `parametrize`:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg1, arg2, text, name", params(),
                         ids=[p[3] for p in params()])
def test_parse(arg1, arg2, text, name):
    _testStep(arg1, arg2, text, name)
```

This outputs something like:

```
$ pytest -vv
...
test_steps.py::test_parse[ZERO_STEPS] PASSED
test_steps.py::test_parse[ONE_STEP] PASSED
```

Note that I have set the test ids to the `name` argument to avoid to have unreadable test names. This is just an example, but it makes sense to adapt `ids` because of the long strings. Without that, the output would look something like this:

```
test_steps.py::test_parse[1-1-\n# ---\n\nfoo = "bar"\n\n# +\nimport tensorflow\n-ZERO_STEPS] PASSED
test_steps.py::test_parse[1-2-\n# something sensible\n-ONE_STEP] PASSED
```

which is not exactly readable.